# Using ng-model and ng-if to show elements based on value - Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

So in AngularJS i was using the following to show specific form elements based on a value that is captured by a model:

```
<fieldset class="full-width sm-padding">
                <label>Do you have any major medical conditions such as 
heart conditions, cancer or diabetes?</label>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="medicalCondition" value="yes" 
tabindex="16" ng-model="clientDetails.medicalCondition">Yes<br>
                </div>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="medicalCondition" value="no" 
tabindex="17" ng-model="clientDetails.medicalCondition">No<br>
                </div>
            </fieldset>


            <fieldset class="full-width sm-padding" ng-
if="clientDetails.medicalCondition == 'yes'">
                <label>Are you currently taking any medication or do you 
have any other medical conditions? For example HBP, Cholesterol, Asthma, 
Depression? (Both lives if cover for couple)</label>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="otherMedicalCondition" 
value="yes" tabindex="18" ng-
model="clientDetails.otherMedicalCondition">Yes<br>
                </div>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="otherMedicalCondition" 
value="no" tabindex="19" ng-
model="clientDetails.otherMedicalCondition">No<br>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

How can I do the same thing in Angular 2?

Have tried this but not working:

```
<fieldset class="full-width sm-padding">
                <label>Do you smoke?</label>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="smoker" value="yes" 
tabindex="12" [(ngModel)] = "clientDetails.smoker">Yes<br>
                </div>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="smoker" value="no" tabindex="13" [(ngModel)] = "clientDetails.smoker">No<br>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="full-width flex" *ngIf="clientDetails.smoker === 
'Yes'">
                <fieldset class="one-quarter sm-padding">
                    <label>What do you smoke?</label>
                    <input list="whatDoYouSmoke" name="whatDoYouSmoke" 
 tabindex="14">
                    <datalist id="whatDoYouSmoke">
                        <option value="Cigarettes">
                        <option value="Cigars">
                        <option value="Pipe">
                        <option value="E-Cigs">
                        <option value="Other">
                    </datalist>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="one-quarter sm-padding">
                    <label>How many per day?</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="howManySmokesPerDay" 
tabindex="15">
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Have tried so many different options but can't quite get it to work!

thanks

Comment: That's a fun question, I so often had problems with `*ngIf` that I gave up trying to understand it and went to use `[hidden]="<condition>"` instead. I still don't know how `*ngIf` works

Comment: How would I use that in the above code? [hidden]="smoker.yes || smoker.no"?

Comment: `[hidden]="smoker === 'no'"`. Though, you've got some really relevant answers down here.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is that you have typed `[(ngModel)] = ""`, try without spaces like: `[(ngModel)]=""`. Also noticed that in your `*ngIf="clientDetails.smoker === 
'Yes'"`, try with a little 'y' in yes as: `*ngIf="clientDetails.smoker === 
'yes'"`. Since you are setting the value to "yes" and not "Yes" in your radio button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a case problem in the Angular version. The first 'yes' starts with a lower case y and a second 'Yes' with a upper case Y.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there looking for a solution to this, I ended up doing the following:

```
<fieldset class="full-width sm-padding">
                <label>Do you smoke?</label>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="smoker" [(ngModel)]="smoker" 
[value]="true" [checked]="smoker" /> Yes<br>
                </div>
                <div class="inline-flex">
                    <input type="radio" name="smoker" [(ngModel)]="smoker" 
[value]="false" [checked]="!smoker" /> No<br>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="full-width flex" *ngIf="smoker">
                <fieldset class="one-quarter sm-padding">
                    <label>What do you smoke?</label>
                    <input list="whatDoYouSmoke" name="whatDoYouSmoke" tabindex="14">
                    <datalist id="whatDoYouSmoke">
                        <option value="Cigarettes">
                        <option value="Cigars">
                        <option value="Pipe">
                        <option value="E-Cigs">
                        <option value="Other">
                    </datalist>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="one-quarter sm-padding">
                    <label>How many per day?</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="howManySmokesPerDay" 
tabindex="15">
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```